# Not able to change state in react even after setting the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, solidity, ethers.js

When I am trying to print defaultAccount State as shown below code, **it still showing null even after setting it to the metamask account as shown in picture below**, it is throwing me a null value, when printing defaultAccount. **(Please refer error in the below Image)**

```
 class App extends Component {
constructor(){
super()
this.state={
  defaultAccount:null,
  provider:null,
  connectState:false,
  ethers:null,
  gameContract:null
}

this.loadWindow=this.loadWindow.bind(this)
}



async loadWindow(){
if (window.ethereum){
  try{
    const accounts =await window.ethereum.request({method: 'eth_requestAccounts',});
    console.log(accounts[0])
    const contractAbi=[
      "function getRandomNumber() public returns(bytes32 requestId)",
      "function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 requestId,uint randomness) internal override",
      "function contractBalance() public view returns(uint)"
    ]
    const provider=  new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum,"any")
    const signer = await provider.getSigner()
    const gameContract=new ethers.Contract("0x6cEB2a506b6b1145241BC92D4CFD94aE5588eB18",contractAbi,signer)

    this.setState({defaultAccount:accounts[0],connectState:true,provider:provider,ethers:ethers,gameContract:gameContract});
    
    
    console.log(this.state.defaultAccount)
  }catch(e){
console.log(e)
  }
  
  window.alert("Wallet Connected..")
}
else{
  window.alert("Metamask Not Found..")
}

}
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrxCi.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The reason the `console.log` is printing null, is because the setState updates in React happen asynchronously. This is to increase the performance of React. This is explained more in detail [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous).

If you want to log the state directly after it has been updated, you can add a callback function to the setState call like this:

```js
    this.setState({defaultAccount:accounts[0],connectState:true,provider:provider,ethers:ethers,gameContract:gameContract}, () => console.log(this.state.defaultAccount));
```